# android library access App Scope

Tags: java, android

i am in the process of splitting some code  of my android project out to a library - using artifactory to publish/deploy.

the publishing works.

but  i am in the situation that a few classes that should be now in the lib.

have imports like this:

`import com.mycomp.App;
import com.mycomp.restinterface.RestInterface`

working with calls like this:

`public RestInterface service = App.rest(RestInterface.class);`

whereas my library is in this namespace `com.mycomp.sharedlib`

and a few other referencing classes from the app, wich the library now does not know anything about, and all other apps using the same library wont be either.

what is the deal in java to solve the problem, in C i think i would mess arround with a view void* pointers.

regards
helmut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the classes in those imports inside the Library? If not I think it is behaving by design. You will need to refactor your library to not use any classes not within the library/system. Because my understanding is that the library is compiled before the application so therefore it needs to be self-contained.

Comment: ok ended up refactoring the whole thing that it is self-contained - THX anyway